# getting image on same line

Tags: html, css, drupal, web, drupal-7

I'm developing a website using drupal's (7.14) Marinelli theme as a template. I'm currently fighting with getting the main menu onto the same line as the logo. The url of my page is http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/ - can anybody help me on how I have to set the css properties or put the html together to get this aligned properly? The icon should be on the left side of the main menu and the yallow background is just for debugging reason.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!
The code in page.tpl.php currently looks like this:

```
  <div style="background:#000; height:85px; position:fixed; top:0px; width:100%; text-align: right;padding-right:-20px; filter:alpha(opacity=60);border-bottom:1px solid #999;">
<div style="text-align: left;
            top:0px;
            width:70%;
            padding-left:100px;
            padding-right:auto;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            background-color:#FFFF00;"><?php if($logo):print $imagelogo;endif ?>
<div id="navigation-primary" class="sitemenu">
  <?php print $mainmenu; ?>    
</div></div>
```

Comment: I've never heard of `yallow`. What's its hex value?

Comment: I've not heard of yallow either but yellow is #FFFF00 actually - replaced..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to set `position:absolute` on both `divs` together with a `top`: and `margin-left`: property to always fix them relatively. You could also `float` them both left for instance, set a `width` property and a `margin-left` on the right `div`.

Comment: Hi There,Thanks for the reply - this kinda worked but now I can't get the logo on the left side of the menu: http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/ any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Good! You're welcome. You should also probably fix the `z-index` if you insist on having the top menu to follow the scrolling...looks kinda bad when the menu goes underneath the rest.

Comment: Huh, I don't understand, you probably looked at it before I set the z-index. Should be good now, scrolling looks the way i wanted it to be. However, have to fifgure things out if you look at it with a narrow browser window/low resolution... Doesn't quite look like I'd like it to be yet...

Answer (score 0):

Here, this is what you'd need to do : http://jsfiddle.net/Z4EAb/

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the second div (the one that wraps the logo & navigation) is too small to fit the logo and navigation comfortably.

First, please give that second `div` an `id` ("header-wrapper", for instance) and take out the style attribute. Then here's the relevant CSS:

```
#header-wrapper { width: 1038px; margin: 0 auto; }
#logo { top: 15px; position: relative; }
#navigation-primary { float: left; margin-left: 50px; padding-top: 34px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid of using negative margins to position things around each other.

See also:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/